# TSQL conditional where clause issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, where-clause

I have the below query that I need to make a change to and I'm struggling to term the where clause.

The change required is regarding the parameters `@EquipmentBreakdown` & `@PropertyCasualty`. At the moment they works as expected but I need a new condition.

*Current Conditions :*

```
@EquipmentBreakdown = 0 AND  @PropertyCasualty = 0  Return all rows

@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND  @PropertyCasualty = 0  Return all rows where LCRep.EB = 1 

@EquipmentBreakdown = 0 AND  @PropertyCasualty = 1  Return all rows where LCRep.PC = 1
```

*New Condition* :

```
@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND  @PropertyCasualty = 1  Return all rows
```

How do I term the where clause to capture the new condition while maintaining the existing logic?

*Query :*

```
SELECT 'Month' AS [Period],
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionCode,'') AS RegionCode,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionName,'') AS RegionName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    SR01.ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(LCRep.RepName,'') AS RepName,
    SUM(ISNULL(RequestsOnSiteView.CountOfRequests,0)) AS RequestsOnSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(HoursOnSiteView.SumHours,0)) AS HoursOnSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(RequestsOffSiteView.CountOfRequests,0)) AS RequestsOffSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(HoursOffSiteView.SumHours,0)) AS HoursOffSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(RequestsNonReportView.CountOfRequests,0)) AS RequestsNonReport,
    SUM(ISNULL(HoursNonReportView.SumHours,0)) AS HoursNonReport
FROM dbo.SR01
    LEFT JOIN dbo.HoursOnSiteView ON HoursOnSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.HoursOffSiteView ON HoursOffSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.HoursNonReportView ON HoursNonReportView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsOnSiteView ON RequestsOnSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsOffSiteView ON RequestsOffSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsNonReportView ON RequestsNonReportView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LCRep ON SR01.ServicingRep = LCRep.RepID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch ON SR01.ServicingBranch = Branch.BranchID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Region ON Region.RegionCode = Branch.Region
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Zone ON Zone.ZoneAbbrev = Region.Zone 
WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
    AND SR01.[Status]='X'
    AND SR01.RequestType <> 'MN' 
    AND SR01.DateComplete BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateTo), 0) AND @DateTo
    AND Zone.ZoneID IN (@Zone)
    AND Region.RegionCode IN (@Region)
    AND Branch.BranchID IN (@Branch)
    AND LCRep.RepID IN(@RepID)  
    AND (@EquipmentBreakdown = 0 OR (LCRep.EB = @EquipmentBreakdown)) 
    AND (@PropertyCasualty = 0 OR (LCRep.PC = @PropertyCasualty))
GROUP BY Zone.ZoneID, Zone.ZoneName, Region.RegionCode, Region.RegionName, Branch.BranchID, BranchName, SR01.ServicingRep, LCRep.RepName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like the below is a solution that works but I'm not sure if its an ideal solution.

```
SELECT 'Month' AS [Period],
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionCode,'') AS RegionCode,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionName,'') AS RegionName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    SR01.ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(LCRep.RepName,'') AS RepName,
    SUM(ISNULL(RequestsOnSiteView.CountOfRequests,0)) AS RequestsOnSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(HoursOnSiteView.SumHours,0)) AS HoursOnSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(RequestsOffSiteView.CountOfRequests,0)) AS RequestsOffSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(HoursOffSiteView.SumHours,0)) AS HoursOffSite,
    SUM(ISNULL(RequestsNonReportView.CountOfRequests,0)) AS RequestsNonReport,
    SUM(ISNULL(HoursNonReportView.SumHours,0)) AS HoursNonReport
FROM dbo.SR01
    LEFT JOIN dbo.HoursOnSiteView ON HoursOnSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.HoursOffSiteView ON HoursOffSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.HoursNonReportView ON HoursNonReportView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsOnSiteView ON RequestsOnSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsOffSiteView ON RequestsOffSiteView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsNonReportView ON RequestsNonReportView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LCRep ON SR01.ServicingRep = LCRep.RepID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch ON SR01.ServicingBranch = Branch.BranchID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Region ON Region.RegionCode = Branch.Region
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Zone ON Zone.ZoneAbbrev = Region.Zone 
WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
    AND SR01.[Status]='X'
    AND SR01.RequestType <> 'MN' 
    AND SR01.DateComplete BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateTo), 0) AND @DateTo
    AND (@EquipmentBreakdown = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.EB = @EquipmentBreakdown)) 
    AND (@PropertyCasualty = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.PC = @PropertyCasualty))
GROUP BY Zone.ZoneID, Zone.ZoneName, Region.RegionCode, Region.RegionName, Branch.BranchID, BranchName, SR01.ServicingRep, LCRep.RepName
```